# how can i handle ORA-00917 error exception block

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Have created table x with two columns x and name.
Have written an anonymous block to catch errors while inserting data in table.but im not able to handle ORA-00917 error even if i have mentioned it in the exception and have also written an others exception part.

```
CREATE TABLE X 
(   X    NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    NAME VARCHAR2(100));
```

The code

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 
  EXCEPTION_HANDLE6 EXCEPTION;    
  pragma exception_init(EXCEPTION_HANDLE6, -00917);

BEGIN
  insert into x values ('2','GOVIND NAGAR 'C'BLK KANPUR' );

EXCEPTION
  WHEN EXCEPTION_HANDLE6 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('MISSING COMMA');
  WHEN others THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('other error ');
END;
```

I'm getting error directly displayed instead of message missing comma or other error

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-00917: missing comma

I believe you're talking about the `INSERT` statement (which looks wrong anyway, because of wrongly written single quotes):

```
insert into x values ('2','GOVIND NAGAR 'C'BLK KANPUR' );
```

The fact is: your code won't compile, and error you get is at compilation, not execution (runtime) so you can't handle it that way. You'll have to fix the error first, and then run your code.

Should be

```
insert into x values ('2','GOVIND NAGAR ''C''BLK KANPUR' );
```

(note two single quotes), or

```
insert into x values ('2',q'['GOVIND NAGAR 'C'BLK KANPUR']' );
```

Comment: hi littlefoot, that means compilation error cannot be handled in exception block and only run time errors can be handled?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell.